# Azure Website Keeps Trying to Connect to Old Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

For some reason, when I published my site to Azure from Visual Studio, it created a new DB. My DB was named something like MySiteDB and it created a database called mysite_db. I finally found the issue in the publish settings and changed it so that it pointed to the right database. I then deleted the old database since it was essentially empty. However, it's still trying to connect to the old database (that is, mysite_db). Where else could this be set? I've searched the entire solution for mysite_db and it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: As far as I can remember, the .PublishSettings file does not contain any information related to databases. Have you checked your Web.config files? If you go to the Management Portal after you publish, what does the "connection strings" section say?

Comment: Where exactly can I find this? I go to Authorizing and Security and it gives me the connection string I should use (and says "your password here" for the password). Is this what you meant?

Comment: I meant the connection string section of the Website. http://www.typecastexception.com/image.axd?picture=azure-configuration-connection-strings1.png

Comment: That was it! I didn't know there was a configuration there. I'll have to explore this panel a bit more. Thanks! Can't imagine why it changed it in the first place...

Comment: :) When you perform a publish, that bit is supposed to be updated with the connection string data of your Web.config files.

Comment: As in I should have done it? I'm still new to this, so that's good to know! Thanks again!

Comment: No no, the publishing system updates that value. Just make sure that the connection string in your Web.config file matches the one you see in the Portal after publishing.